# Using FontAwesome in jekyll project with grunt and bower

Tags: gruntjs, jekyll, bower

I'm trying to use [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) in my jekyll project. I generated it using yeoman (`generator-jekyllrb`) and I'm using Grunt and Bower. I installed the font using bower: `bower install fontawesome` and it has been installed in my `app/_bower_components` directory. My question is how can I access it? Here's what's in the `app/_bower_components/fontawesome` directory:

```
fontawesome
├── css
│   ├── font-awesome.css
│   └── font-awesome.min.css
├── fonts
│   ├── FontAwesome.otf
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.eot
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.svg
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.ttf
│   └── fontawesome-webfont.woff
├── less
│   └── ...
└── scss
    └── ...
```

In `app/_bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css` I have this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

In my html file I have this:

```
<!-- build:css({app,.tmp}) /css/main.css -->
<!-- Syntax highlighting CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/syntax.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

When I try it locally everything works fine, however, when I build it to a static site I get 404 not found because there is not directory `fonts` (grunt minifies and merges all the .css files into one and doesn't make `fonts` directory with the font itself):

```
dist
├── 404.html
├── css
│   └── main.0df9.css
├── img
│   └── okay.d42b.png
├── index.html
├── jekyll
│   └── update
│       └── 2014
│           └── 06
│               └── 16
│                   ├── test-first-post.html
│                   ├── welcome-to-jekyll.html
│                   └── yo-jekyllrb.html
├── js
│   └── scripts.472f.js
└── search.json
```

If I copy the font files into my `app/fonts` (which I think is not the best way to do it) it doesn't work either because grunt changes their names. So, what should I do?

Here's my [Gruntfile](http://pastebin.com/skESWMuu) if you need it.

I also tried to add fontawesome directory into my Gruntfile (line 270):

```
dist: {
  files: [{
    expand: true,
    dot: true,
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
    src: [
      // Jekyll processes and moves HTML and text files.
      // Usemin moves CSS and javascript inside of Usemin blocks.
      // Copy moves asset files and directories.
      'img/**/*',
      'fonts/**/*',
      // Like Jekyll, exclude files & folders prefixed with an underscore.
      '!**/_*{,/**}',
      // Explicitly add any files your site needs for distribution here.
      // '_bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
      //'favicon.ico',
      //'apple-touch*.png'
    ],
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
  }]
},
```

And it works perfectly fine, it generates a working static site but when I deploy it (I'm using GitHub Pages) it just doesn't find anything in the `_bower_components` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an import to the fontawesome css from `/app/css/main.css` so that it will be included in your compiled `/dist/css/main.css` because the _bower_components folder will not be present in `/dist/`.

You also need to either manually copy the font files themselves into your /app/fonts directory or set up Grunt to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The **absolute easiest** way to get Font Awesome in a project is by simply using the CDN option detailed here:

[Get Started with Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/)

You can simply drop `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` into `_includes/head.html` and things like `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>` will magically work everywhere.

**If you need/prefer to serve everything locally, read on...**

Notice that in `dist/` directory, there is no folder `bower_components/`. This means 1) that grunt is not copying over any bower assets to the final build (`grunt build`) and 2) the `<link>` reference in your html file to `/_bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css` will be broken.

## Step 1 (Optional)

Include the contents of `app/_bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css` in your main sass file like this:

```
// .scss (not .sass) syntax
@import "path/to/font-awesome.css";
```

Now, when you run `grunt build`, the contents of `font-awesome.css` will be added to the final stylesheet in `dist`.

This means you can delete this line from your html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

(Don't worry about loosing the minification, since that will still happen on `grunt build`.)

Now you've got all styles conveniently controlled in the sass file, and saved an http request in the process. (fist-bump)

## Step 2

You have the CSS for font-awesome, but now these links will be broken in the final build:

```
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0');
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
```

This is becuase `grunt` doesn't know about the files in `/_bower_components/fontawesome/fonts/` until you tell it.

Notice this bit of your `Gruntfile.js`:

```
copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          src: [
            // Jekyll processes and moves HTML and text files.
            // Usemin moves CSS and javascript inside of Usemin blocks.
            // Copy moves asset files and directories.
            'img/**/*',
            'fonts/**/*',
            // Like Jekyll, exclude files & folders prefixed with an underscore.
            '!**/_*{,/**}',
            // Explicitly add any files your site needs for distribution here.
            // '_bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
            //'favicon.ico',
            //'apple-touch*.png'
          ],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      },
```

The `copy:` task is designed for any assets you need in your `dist` that arent't already handled by other tasks such as `compass` or `usemin`.

Now we have a couple of options

**Option 1**

Uncomment `'_bower_components/jquery/jquery.js'` above and change it to `'_bower_components/fontawesome/fonts/**/*'`. Now the contents of `fontawesome/fonts` will be included in the final `dist`.

Next, update `/_bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css` to reflect the new file path:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../_bower_components/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0');
  src: url('../_bower_components/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../_bower_components/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0') format('woff'), url('../_bower_components/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0') format('truetype'), url('../_bower_components/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**Caveat:** Updating font-awesome via bower will overwrite these changes, and you'll have to fix it **each time**. Annoying.

So what can we do?

**Option 2 (my favorite)**

Let's get the fonts from `/_bower_components/fontawesome/fonts/` into `<%= yeoman.app %>/fonts/` *before* `fonts/**/*` is copied over to `dist` by grunt. Luckily, the `files:` task is already an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), so we can just add another [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) above the existing one.

Here's the updated section of `Gruntfile.js`:

```
copy: {
          dist: {
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              dot: true,
              cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
              src: [
                // Jekyll processes and moves HTML and text files.
                // Usemin moves CSS and javascript inside of Usemin blocks.
                // Copy moves asset files and directories.
                'img/**/*',
                'fonts/**/*',
                // Like Jekyll, exclude files & folders prefixed with an underscore.
                '!**/_*{,/**}',
                // Explicitly add any files your site needs for distribution here.
                // '_bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
                //'favicon.ico',
                //'apple-touch*.png'
              ],
              dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            },{
              // Copy font awesome fonts
              expand: true,
              cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
              src: [
                '_bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/**/*',
              ],
              dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts/'
            }]
          },
```

Also note that the `filerev:` task renames certain assets in `dist` to allow for easy cache-busting on deploy. If after these steps the font path in the built css doesn't match the path in `dist/fonts`, try commenting out the relevant line in the `filerev:` task in `Gruntfile.js`:

```
filerev: {
      options: {
        length: 4
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/js/**/*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/**/*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img/**/*.{gif,jpg,jpeg,png,svg,webp}',
            // '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts/**/*.{eot*,otf,svg,ttf,woff}'
          ]
        }]
      }
    },
```